# SYMPY : How to refine a whole matrix after eigenvector calculation?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to use sympy to calculate eigenvectors and I did some trials with jupyter notebook

```
from sympy import *
a,b=symbols("a b", real=True)
M  = Matrix([[a,b],[b,-a]])
[T, D] = M.diagonalize(normalize=true)
```

To check normalization, I calculated the vector norm : `simplify(T[0,0]**2+T[1,0]**2)`. But the ouput is very large. It seems that **a** and **b** are not considered as real (squares of absolute values are not simplify to square). To obtain the expected value : **1**, I must use

```
T00ref=refine(T[0,0],Q.real(a) & Q.real(b))
T10ref=refine(T[1,0],Q.real(a) & Q.real(b))
simplify(T00ref**2+T10ref**2)
```

Why must I refine the matrix elements ?
And moreover,

```
Tref=refine(T,Q.real(a) & Q.real(b))
simplify(Tref[0,0]**2+Tref[1,0]**2)
```

does not work. I could not refine the whole matrix.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: re: *"I could not refine the whole matrix."*  you can use [applyfunc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/common.html#sympy.matrices.common.MatrixCommon.applyfunc) as follows: `T.applyfunc(lambda u: refine(u,Q.real(a) & Q.real(b)))`

Comment: Both `refine` and `simplify` could be improved here. You should open an issue on github