# SYMPY : How to simplify function with exp(-i.w.t) term?

Tags: sympy

I use sympy to do symbolic computation with imaginary number exponential terms (*exp(i.a)*), but I have problem with simplification.
For example, I obtained the following function (after some hamiltonian diagonalisation and time evolution, this is not the problem in this question):

```
import sympy as sp
w, th, t =sp.symbols("omega theta t", real=True)
myFunc = (sp.exp(sp.I*w*t)*sp.sin(th)**2 + sp.exp(-sp.I*w*t)*sp.cos(th)**2)*(sp.exp(sp.I*w*t)*sp.cos(th)**2 + sp.exp(-sp.I*w*t)*sp.sin(th)**2) + sp.sin(2*th)**2*sp.sin(w*t)**2
```

During calculation, sin(w.t) and cos(w.t) terms are implicitly generated from exp(-i.wt) and exp(i.wt). This is normal. But, I could not manage to simplify them with the different methods from https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html.

However, in the example above, if sinus(w.t) is, explicitly, substituted by *(exp(i.w.t)-exp(-i.w.t)) /(2.i)*)

```
firstStep=myFunc.subs(sp.sin(w*t),((sp.exp(sp.I*w*t)-sp.exp(-sp.I*w*t))/(2*sp.I)))
```

(`sp.simplify(firstStep)`) outputs **1**, as expected.

Are there some sympy functions to simplify **directly** such expressions with exp(i.wt), exp(-i.wt) terms mixed with sin(wt), cos(wt) terms   ?

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of functions for manipulating an expression like this. The simplest way to simplify is to either rewrite exp as sin or rewrite sin as exp:

```
In [22]: myFunc
Out[22]: 
⎛ ⅈ⋅ω⋅t    2       -ⅈ⋅ω⋅t    2   ⎞ ⎛ ⅈ⋅ω⋅t    2       -ⅈ⋅ω⋅t    2   ⎞      2         2     
⎝ℯ     ⋅sin (θ) + ℯ      ⋅cos (θ)⎠⋅⎝ℯ     ⋅cos (θ) + ℯ      ⋅sin (θ)⎠ + sin (2⋅θ)⋅sin (ω⋅t)

In [23]: myFunc.expand()
Out[23]: 
 2⋅ⅈ⋅ω⋅t    2       2         4         2         2           4       -2⋅ⅈ⋅ω⋅t    2       2   
ℯ       ⋅sin (θ)⋅cos (θ) + sin (θ) + sin (2⋅θ)⋅sin (ω⋅t) + cos (θ) + ℯ        ⋅sin (θ)⋅cos (θ)

In [24]: myFunc.rewrite(exp)
Out[24]: 
⎛              2                         2       ⎞ ⎛              2                        2        ⎞                     2                  
⎜⎛ ⅈ⋅θ    -ⅈ⋅θ⎞            ⎛ ⅈ⋅θ    -ⅈ⋅θ⎞   ⅈ⋅ω⋅t⎟ ⎜⎛ ⅈ⋅θ    -ⅈ⋅θ⎞           ⎛ ⅈ⋅θ    -ⅈ⋅θ⎞   -ⅈ⋅ω⋅t⎟   ⎛ 2⋅ⅈ⋅θ    -2⋅ⅈ⋅θ⎞  ⎛ ⅈ⋅ω⋅t    -ⅈ⋅ω⋅t
⎜⎜ℯ      ℯ    ⎟   -ⅈ⋅ω⋅t   ⎝ℯ    - ℯ    ⎠ ⋅ℯ     ⎟ ⎜⎜ℯ      ℯ    ⎟   ⅈ⋅ω⋅t   ⎝ℯ    - ℯ    ⎠ ⋅ℯ      ⎟   ⎝ℯ      - ℯ      ⎠ ⋅⎝ℯ      - ℯ      
⎜⎜──── + ─────⎟ ⋅ℯ       - ──────────────────────⎟⋅⎜⎜──── + ─────⎟ ⋅ℯ      - ───────────────────────⎟ + ─────────────────────────────────────
⎝⎝ 2       2  ⎠                      4           ⎠ ⎝⎝ 2       2  ⎠                      4           ⎠                      16                

 2
⎞ 
⎠ 
──
  

In [25]: myFunc.rewrite(exp).expand()
Out[25]: 1

In [26]: myFunc.rewrite(sin)
Out[26]: 
⎛                            2                                 2⎛    π⎞⎞ ⎛                            2⎛    π⎞                              2
⎜(-ⅈ⋅sin(ω⋅t) + cos(ω⋅t))⋅sin (θ) + (ⅈ⋅sin(ω⋅t) + cos(ω⋅t))⋅sin ⎜θ + ─⎟⎟⋅⎜(-ⅈ⋅sin(ω⋅t) + cos(ω⋅t))⋅sin ⎜θ + ─⎟ + (ⅈ⋅sin(ω⋅t) + cos(ω⋅t))⋅sin 
⎝                                                               ⎝    2⎠⎠ ⎝                             ⎝    2⎠                               

   ⎞      2         2     
(θ)⎟ + sin (2⋅θ)⋅sin (ω⋅t)
   ⎠                      

In [27]: myFunc.rewrite(sin).expand()
Out[27]: 
   4       2           4       2             2       2         2⎛    π⎞        2       2⎛    π⎞    2           2         2           2       
sin (θ)⋅sin (ω⋅t) + sin (θ)⋅cos (ω⋅t) - 2⋅sin (θ)⋅sin (ω⋅t)⋅sin ⎜θ + ─⎟ + 2⋅sin (θ)⋅sin ⎜θ + ─⎟⋅cos (ω⋅t) + sin (2⋅θ)⋅sin (ω⋅t) + sin (ω⋅t)⋅s
                                                                ⎝    2⎠                 ⎝    2⎠                                              

  4⎛    π⎞      4⎛    π⎞    2     
in ⎜θ + ─⎟ + sin ⎜θ + ─⎟⋅cos (ω⋅t)
   ⎝    2⎠       ⎝    2⎠          

In [28]: myFunc.rewrite(sin).expand().trigsimp()
Out[28]: 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. *rewrite* was the secret. I should have asked before.

Comment: As you are a sympy specialist, do you have an idea about this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/q/66397006/7462275 ? I hope I do not waste your time.